# Declaration of validationDefault in Cakephp 4.0

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to create a site with CakePHP 4.0, but can't get the validation rules to work. I read the documentation, but wasn't sure where I was supposed to put the validationDefault function.  I've put it in UsersTable.php, which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config): void {

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Requests')
                ->setDependent(true);

        $this->hasMany('Offers')
                ->setDependent(true);

    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {

        $validator->notEmptyString('email', 'Please enter your email address')
                  ->notEmptyString('name', 'Please enter a name');

        return $validator;
    }
}

?>
```

So I'm expecting that if a user tries to sign in without an email or name, it should throw an error.

The form I have for registration is:

```
        echo $this->Form->create();
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('email');
        echo $this->Form->control('password', array('type' => 'password'));
        echo $this->Form->control('confirm_password', array('type' => 'password'));
        echo $this->Form->button('Register');
        echo $this->Form->end();
```

and that sends the data to UsersController.php, which contains:

```
public function login() {

                // Otherwise, we're registering
                $users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
                $user = $users->newEntity($this->request->getData());
                if ($users->save($user)) {
                    $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
                    if ($result->isValid()) {
                        $target = '/users/home';
                        return $this->redirect($target);
                    }
                }else {
                    $this->Flash->error('Please fix errors below');
                }
                exit;
            }

        }

    }
```

When I try to register without entering a name and email, I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of App\Model\Table\UsersTable::validationDefault(Cake\Validation\Validator $validator) must be compatible with Cake\ORM\Table::validationDefault(Cake\Validation\Validator $validator): Cake\Validation\Validator in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php on line 26
```

I can't see any obvious problems with my code. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: To avoid problems, create your MVC with bake commands. Also in your code editor use intelephense plugins witch help you to write code without errors.

Comment: I tried to do that, but bake won't connect to the database in my terminal, and I didn't get anywhere with debugging it, so it seemed faster to just build what I needed myself! Thanks though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration of the `validationDefault` function in Cake is:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
```

Your declaration is just

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
```

You need to add the return type declaration at the end in order to match. The docs don't seem to mention that, you might want to raise an issue on that.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I haven't seen that mentioned anywhere.  I'll raise an issue as you suggest.